# accept nested json using post in plumber and accepts few arguments plumber

Tags: r, api, plumber

This is my api which accepts parameters.

```
#' @param sepal.Length
#' @param Sepal.Width
#' @param Petal.Length
#' @param petal.Width
#' @post /predict
#' @html
calculate_prediction <- function(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Petal.Width) {
}
```

My input Json is :

```
{
    "args":{
"Sepal.Length":5.1,
"Sepal.Width":3.5,
"Petal.Length":1.4,
"Petal.Width":0.2
},
"modelname":"v1.1",
"version":2
}
```

How can i send json and access parameters inside function

Comment: Have you tried `jsonlite` or `rjson`?

Comment: How does this both help, Arguments  are different from in the  json. Can you please brief about this

Comment: You're right, I don't know exactly how it would help: I have no idea how your function is being called, and there is no clear context of what the json is doing here. Perhaps you can explain where the json is coming from?